# Can a University put a Creative Commons document containing a NonCommercial element (NC) behind a wall?

Tags: creative-commons, license

Can a University force web visitors to connect with their University ID to access a document licensed under Creative Commons containing a NonCommercial element (NC)?

Enrolling into at University a student often costs money, and the ability to access the document could be viewed as a perk for employees (i.e. indirect compensation): as a result, I wonder whether putting the document behind the University wall is considered as a commercial use of the document.

For example, I see that Stanford University forces web visitors to log in with their university account to access this CC BY-NC [document](http://purl.stanford.edu/tx793sf6804):

[image]

Comment: You pay your ISP to access NC material on the web, because you pay them to access all material on the web: is that an issue? No, of course it isn't. And the university doesn't ask for a payment for each access to an NC paper, does it?

Comment: If you take 5 NC articles, append them and sell them as a book, you might run into trouble. If you take 1000 NC articles, put them on a FTP, and sell the access, I don't know what happens. Etc. I wonder from what point NC starts.

Comment: As a separate matter, as I understand it, in the US only the copyright holder can enforce a license, so you'd have to get the author to challenge them putting it behind a Stanford wall (and if the author, as part of some paperwork, signed something letting Stanford post it behind a Stanford wall, CC-NC doesn't apply because they aren't using it under that license).

Answer (score 9):

Creative Commons "NonCommercial" prohibits uses that are ["primarily intended for or directed toward commercial advantage or monetary compensation."](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Does_my_use_violate_the_NonCommercial_clause_of_the_licenses.3F)  Under U.S. law, where *exactly* the boundary lies can only ultimately be determined by development of precedent in case law, since the U.S. has a [common-law legal system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law).

It is pretty clear, though, that this type of use would be non-infringing, for the following reasons:

1. Virtually no person pays to become a university student for the *primary* reason of access to online documents.  Likewise, it is an exceedingly minor perk for employees and could not be considered to give the university a significant commercial advantage (rare historical documents might be a different matter).
2. The actual barrier is a University ID, which can typically also be acquired in many ways that do not involve compensation passing in either direction (e.g. research affiliates).